Checking unchecking inputfield checkbox in visualforce page
public Boolean getRenderComplaintsFields(){
renderComplaints=false;
if(theCase.Function__c == 'Complaint' || theCase.Request_Type__c == 'Complaint'
|| (theCase.Function__c == 'Group Claims' && theCase.Request_Type__c == null)
|| (theCase.Function__c == 'Group Policy Admin' && theCase.Request_Type__c == null)
|| (theCase.Function__c == 'Group Sales' && theCase.Request_Type__c == null)
|| (theCase.Function__c == 'Group Underwriting' && theCase.Request_Type__c == null)
|| (theCase.Function__c == 'Sales & Distribution' && theCase.Request_Type__c == null)
|| (theCase.Function__c == 'Advice - Zurich Assure' && theCase.Request_Type__c == null)
){
renderComplaints=true;
}else if(theCase.Function__c == 'General Insurance' && theCase.Request_Type__c == null){

theCase.NonMigratedPolicyComplaint__c=true;
callerRelationNonMigratedPolicy();
renderComplaints=true;
}else{
nonMigratedFlagChecked=false;
theCase.NonMigratedPolicyComplaint__c=false;
if(selectablePolicies == null || selectablePolicies.size() == 0){
clientRoles = new List();
}
}
return renderComplaints;
}
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem rendered="{!RenderComplaintsFields}">
<apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Case.fields.NonMigratedPolicyComplaint__c.label}" for="nonMigratedPolicy" />
<apex:actionRegion >
<apex:inputField id="nonMigratedPolicy" value="{!theCase.NonMigratedPolicyComplaint__c}">
<apex:actionSupport status="submitStatus" action="{!callerRelationNonMigratedPolicy}" event="onchange" rerender="caseInfo,caseContacts,callerDetails,caseQuestions,complaintQuestions"/>
</apex:inputField>
</apex:actionRegion>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
I am using above code for making the checkbox field by default checkin when the function field value== General Insurance, it's coming with by default checked but when I try to uncheck it was not working.
I want to display it with checkin when function value equals to General Insurance, but at the same time after displaying it checked, it should be able to uncheck and check based on the user action.
Anyone please help me in this, thanks!

Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. Please format your code using the code block tools so it is readable
